# A program to query Oracle Data Dictionary

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am solving some oracle practice questions in order to prepare for an interview. I am expected to write a script that provides all of the information in, and duplicates the formatting of, Oracle's SQL*Plus describe command and the output should add the comments on the rows.

**Input**: owner and table name.
**Output**: columns for Name, Null?, Type, Comments.

This question got me really confused. I can query the data dictionary effectively but I do not really know what I am really expected to do.

I was able to come up with this but I am left with the comments part.

```
select column_name AS "Name",
       (case when nullable = 'N'
             then 'NOT NULL'
             else null
         end) AS "Null?",
       (case when data_type = 'DATE'
             then data_type
             when data_type = 'NUMBER' and data_scale > 0
             then data_type || '(' || data_precision || ',' || data_scale || ')'
             when data_type = 'NUMBER' and data_scale = 0
             then data_type || '(' || data_precision || ')'
             when data_type = 'VARCHAR2'
             then data_type || '(' || data_length || ')'
        end) AS "Type"
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = UPPER('&table_name')
 order by column_id;
```

Comment: Just google for Execute Immediate for DESC command?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai `execute immediate` only supports SQL and PL/SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it using the `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` dictionary view using single select. If you want it to create the `PL/SQL script` for it then use this query in the `for loop` and use `DBMS_OUTPUT` with the desired formatting to display it into output as following:

```
SQL> DESC EMPLOYEES;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER
 FIRSTNAME                                          VARCHAR2(100)
 CITY                                               VARCHAR2(100)

SQL> column "Name" format a41
SQL> column "Null?" format a8
SQL> column "Type" format a28
SQL> SELECT
  2      COLUMN_NAME   AS "Name",
  3      DECODE(NULLABLE,'N','NOT NULL')      AS "Null?",
  4      DATA_TYPE
  5      || '('
  6      || DATA_LENGTH
  7      || ')' AS "Type"
  8  FROM
  9      USER_TAB_COLUMNS
 10  WHERE
 11      TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEES';

Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(22)
FIRSTNAME                                          VARCHAR2(100)
CITY                                               VARCHAR2(100)

SQL>
```

**-- UPDATE --**

`DESCRIBE` or `DESC` command does not provide the `comment column` as mentioned in the [oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12019.htm) and also according to the following demo.

> The description for tables, views, types and synonyms contains the
>   following information:
>
> each column's name
>
> whether or not null values are allowed (NULL or NOT NULL) for each
>   column
>
> datatype of columns, for example, CHAR, DATE, LONG, LONGRAW, NUMBER,
>   RAW, ROWID, VARCHAR2 (VARCHAR), or XMLType
>
> precision of columns (and scale, if any, for a numeric column)

```
SQL> comment on column EMPLOYEES.ID is 'unique id';

Comment created.

SQL> DESC EMPLOYEES;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER
 FIRSTNAME                                          VARCHAR2(100)
 CITY                                               VARCHAR2(100)

SQL> DESCRIBE EMPLOYEES;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER
 FIRSTNAME                                          VARCHAR2(100)
 CITY                                               VARCHAR2(100)

SQL>
```

If you really want `comment` as part of the result then use the following query:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      UT.COLUMN_NAME   AS "Name",
  3      DECODE(UT.NULLABLE, 'N', 'NOT NULL') AS "Null?",
  4      UT.DATA_TYPE
  5      || '('
  6      || UT.DATA_LENGTH
  7      || ')' AS "Type",
  8      UC.COMMENTS
  9  FROM
 10      USER_TAB_COLUMNS UT
 11      JOIN USER_COL_COMMENTS UC ON ( UT.TABLE_NAME = UC.TABLE_NAME
 12                                     AND UT.COLUMN_NAME = UC.COLUMN_NAME )
 13  WHERE
 14      UT.TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEES';

Name                      Null?    Type                 COMMENTS
------------------------- -------- -------------------- --------------------
ID                        NOT NULL NUMBER(22)           unique id
FIRSTNAME                          VARCHAR2(100)
CITY                               VARCHAR2(100)

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Doesn't include the comments.

Comment: It doesn't include the comment part

Comment: @AbubakarOluyinka - so you get a bonus teaching: don't accept answers until you've checked that they solve your whole problem ;-)

Comment: You will need to do join on `user_col_comments` table to fetch the comment. Give me sometime. I will update the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Just extending the answer from @Tejash. If you want to include the comments column, You can join USER_COL_COLUMNS view in above query -

```
SELECT
        UTC.COLUMN_NAME   AS "Name",
        DECODE(NULLABLE,'N','NOT NULL')      AS "Null?",
        DATA_TYPE
        || '('
        || DATA_LENGTH
        || ')' AS "Type",
        DATA_DEFAULT "Default",
        UCC.COMMENTS "EMPLOYEES"
   FROM
        USER_TAB_COLUMNS UTC
   JOIN USER_COL_COMMENTS UCC ON UTC.COLUMN_NAME = UCC.COLUMN_NAME
                               AND UTC.TABLE_NAME = UCC.TABLE_NAME
   WHERE
       UTC.TABLE_NAME = 'T1';
```

I have added the default column also. [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4da760a741e44f02525a923cdad87ed0) is the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query extended to include comments. Comments come from views like ALL_TAB_COMMENTS and ALL_COL_COMMENTS. The join is a LEFT OUTER JOIN because not all columns have comments.

Note: You should be using ALL_% views because the question says the input includes `owner` which strongly suggests that the input might target another schema, not the one you're connected to. (Possibly it ought to be DBA_% views but `desc` doesn't work for tables on which we have no privileges.)

Also: Your query only handles three data types. It would be wrong for say CLOB or CHAR.

```
select tc.column_name AS "Name",
       (case when tc.nullable = 'N'
             then 'NOT NULL'
             else null
         end) AS "Null?",
       (case when tc.data_type = 'NUMBER' and data_scale > 0
             then tc.data_type || '(' || data_precision || ',' || data_scale || ')'
             when tc.data_type = 'NUMBER' and data_scale = 0
             then tc.data_type || '(' || data_precision || ')'
             when tc.data_type in ('VARCHAR2', 'CHAR')
             then tc.data_type || '(' || data_length || ')'
             else tc.data_type
        end) AS "Type"
        , cc.comments
  from all_tab_columns tc
       left outer join all_col_columns cc
          on   cc.owner = tc.owner
          and  cc.table_name = tc.table_name
          and  cc.column_name = tc.column_name
 where tc.owner = UPPER('&owner')
 and   tc.table_name = UPPER('&table_name')
 order by tc.column_id;
```